# My blender render is glitching and showing basically nothing

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I've been using blender for about two weeks now and I've rendered a few images with no problems but for some reason this project won't cooperate, I tried all the tips I could find with my own searching but I feel like I'm probably missing something that I have no knowledge about due to being a beginner and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I've attached a photo of my viewport vs the render that come out of it, any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution

I was using a sphere as an emmiter for the particles system and the render is just showing a super close up sphere, i had to uncheck "show emitter"

in particle properties > Render > Show Emitter

Comment: Hi and Welcome! Consider to convert your comment into an answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour